# Combining Disparate Schemas in Postgres - ETL or SQL?

Tags: postgresql, etl

1) We are using Segment to pull event data from our email provider and from our marketing automation provider and we are sending this data (different schemas)  to two separate staging tables in a Postgres DB.

2) We now want to ETL/ELT this data in our Master Postgres DB. We need to a) clean the data and b) normalize the data, and do lookups against FKs in our Master DB.

Is the best way to do the data transformation and lookups via SQL, or via ETL/ELT software?

Thank you for any insight.

Comment: It depends, on the amount of data, the number and types of transformations. If you have few transformations and data you it's easier to write a few queries. If you have a lot of data and/or transformations, an ETL tool is easier and faster.

Comment: I believe tsql is ms procedural language

Comment: Sorry, I  meant "SQL" in the sense that writing the queries by hand.

Comment: Can you recommend an ETL software product that can do this -- take in Postgres as a source and output as Postgres?  I've looked at a few open source products and they don't pull in RDBMS.

Comment: Then they aren't ETL tools. An ETL/ELT tool by definition is a tool that extracts data from databases or files, transforms it and loads it to another database. All have JDBC/ODBC connectors

Comment: What type of tool would it be? I need to pull from Postgres, normalize the data and do FK lookups, and then copy to a second Postgres DB. Thx!